# SSRS show only template

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need some help with SSRS, my report worked fine until I run it couple of times in preview mode in VS. I don't change anything in query or in settings only try it different input parameters, it start show me only empty template.

Comment: there's definitely not enough information for us to help you

Comment: Validate your parameters values, also every time you change parameters from preview press the `refresh` button since VS doesn't query datasets every time you preview the report instead It uses cached data.

Comment: thanks for response, problem is that when i started to try to run my report with parameter it's worked fine, i don't do any changes to something, and i even don't change the parameter, but after couple of time that I run it stop to work in right way and only show me the template

Comment: I'd deploy the report to server just to test. Try restart VS to discard any issue related to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your query, when you are running the report there might be no data available against those parameters. Try running the report with same parameters which you are giving in preview mode, and then share results.